# How to count occurrence of a hard coded string in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Eclipse, i can do this search for a hard coded string, which will tell the count and places where it is occurring.

I couldn't find how to do this in Visual Studio and my google search is not yielding anything on this.

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to find every instance of a certain string (id "string123") or every instance where a variable is set to a string on creation (ie string variableName = "string123")? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Press `ctrl+f`. In find window select "`find in files`" at the top-left instead of `Quick find`. This will show the find result in a new window and you will get all statistics at the bottom of window.

Comment: Shame on me. File types was with wrong extension. Thanks. Now works.

Comment: It would be useful if Visual Studio could show the count in the `Quick find` box, like most of other IDEs / Editors...

Comment: `Ctrl + Shift + F`, not `Ctrl + F`.

Comment: @ellockie
I work around this shortcoming by running a replace of the desired string with something unique - replace gives you the number replaced. The just ctrl-Z to put it all back the way it was.

Answer (score 9):

As of Visual Studio 2015, you now need to do `Ctrl + Shift + F` to pull up the full `Find in Files` menu, which will then give you the stats when you search in the current document.